# Elisp rename macro

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

How can I rename elisp macro? To be more accurate, I want make `defun` to be synonym to `cl-defun`.
I do not care about time or memory overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

I don't think you can do that - at least not easily.

Since `cl-defun` expands to `defun`, you will get an infinite macroexpand loop when using `defun` if you do the obvious `(defalias 'defun 'cl-defun)`.

### The is a way...

So what you need to do is

1. save the original `defun`: `(fset 'defun-original (symbol-function 'defun))`.
2. copy the definition of `cl-defun` in `cl-macs.el`, replacing `defun` with `defun-original`.
3. replace `defun` with `cl-defun` using `defalias`: `(defalias 'defun 'cl-defun)`.

Now, at least, if things go sour, you can restore the original behavior with `(fset 'defun (symbol-function 'defun-original))`.

### ...but you don't want it

However, I think you don't really *want* to do that.

If you want to use a Common Lisp, [use](http://clisp.org) [it](http://sbcl.org). Trying to pretend that you can turn Elisp into CL will cause you nothing but grief. I tried to travel that road 15 years ago - there is no fun there. It should be easier now, at least there is lexical binding, but I still don't think it is worth the effort.

If you want to extend `Emacs`, then using `cl-defun` makes even less sense: your extensions will be useless for others and you won't even be able to ask for help because few people will bother with such a radical change in such a basic functionality for such a tiny gain.

Comment: Why `cl-defun` extensions are useless? `cl-macs.el` is official part of Emacs.

Comment: I am *not* saying it is useless. Feel free to use it! Just don't redefine `defun` to be `cl-defun`!

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can make a synonym very simply with `(defalias 'foo 'cl-defun)`.
But the expansion of a call to `cl-defun` uses `defun`, so if you do `(defalias 'defun 'cl-defun`) you'll get into infinite loops.

You can probably get what you want by replacing `defun` with a macro which either does what `defun` does or what `cl-defun` does, depending on whether the cal uses `cl-defun` features or not.  E.g. using `advice-add` (which is in Emacs's trunk; you can use `defadvice` in older Emacsen to get simlar results) it could look something like the untested code below:

```
(defun my-defun-dispatch (doit name args &rest body)
  (let ((needs-cl nil))
    (dolist (arg args)
      (unless (and (symbolp arg)
                   (or (not (eq ?& (aref (symbol-name arg) 0)))
                       (memq arg '(&optional &rest))))
        (setq needs-cl t)))
    (if needs-cl
        `(cl-defun ,name ,args ,@body)
      (funcall doit name args body))))
(advice-add :around 'defun 'my-defun-dispatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason?

*Maybe* it's safe to do, and I'm sure it's possible, but I'm very dubious that you should be attempting it in the first place if you can't figure out how to go about it. I don't mean that as any kind of insult; I just suspect that a fundamental change like this could easily cause problems, so you ought to have a solid handle on elisp first before trying it.

I realise that's a bit of a non-answer, but I thought it was worth saying.

FYI `cl-defun` is defined in terms of `defun`.