# Elisp how to replace string automatially

Tags: regex, emacs, replace, elisp

For example, when I write a function in elisp, I often type "(defun" as "(defnu".
Can I replace "(defnu" with "(defun" automatically when the typo occurs?
May I put the definition which replace "(defnu" with "(defun" in a hook?
Thanks!

Comment: See [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873346/elisp-rename-macro)

Answer (score 3):

You can use abbrevs for that: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html

Just define the typo as an abbrev, so it gets replaced with the correct version.

Comment: BTW use add-mode-abbrev, not the global-abbrev-table. Otherwise surprising expansions might occur when its not wanted, edit-abbrevs needs follow.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the issue with `defun`, a nice way to do it is with `yasnippet`.

I just type `d` and <kbd>C-o</kbd> (I've bound it to expand).

Here's what it expands to in an Elisp buffer:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: defun
# key: d
# --
(defun $1 ()
  $0)
```

In a Clojure buffer:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: defn
# key: d
# --
(defn $1 [$0]
)
```

In an Octave buffer:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: function
# key: d
# --
function $1 = $2($0)
endfunction
```

Takes the hassle out of boilerplate for multiple languages at once.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches for dealing with this:

1. You can use *abbreviations* in place of a full name.  There are various ways to do this, including Emacs "abbrevs" (see @Tom's reply) and `dabbrev` (see the Emacs manual, node `Dynamic Abbrevs`), and even just `defalias` and `defvaralias`.
2. Some people use *fuzzy matching* to compensate for such typos (misspellings, changed letter order, and some abbreviation: missing letters). There are several [kinds](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion) of fuzzy matching, from simple "scatter" or "flex" matching (missing letters, but same order) to complex (e.g., involving proximity scores).